# Assigning jsp element value to struts2 textfield

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am implementing logic for updating user details so for that i have run hibernate query and desired object of class Applicants now what I want is to use class Applicant object and use property `getApplicantId()` and use it in Struts2 textfield

```
<%
String id="12"; // for not using static Id later i'll fetch Id from session.
UserData data=new UserData();
Applicant applicant=(Applicant)data.fetchUserData(id);
%>
```

Now i want to use JSP's ID in struts2 textfield like

```
<s:textfield name="fName" value="<%=applicant.getApplicantId()%>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Scriptlets can't be used in the Struts2 tags. And I strongly recommend to move it to the action. As a workaround you may use a stringified value

```
<s:textfield name="fName"><%=applicant.getApplicantId()%></s:textfield>
```

Comment: actually i want to give user flexibility to edit his own name for that i need to display his name in text field so he can edit it easily

Comment: then you need to get the name instead of id.

Comment: yes i meant name instead of id. sorry for that still how to i do that without using action class because applicant is click on edit profile and then page is loading and i don`t know how to load action class on page redirect of jsp

Comment: you shouldn't do it without action class better map the action to the url that returns result having input type that point to the jsp.